# Swift - How to call function specific date and time

Tags: swift

How can I run a function every day after 13:00 pm even if the application is not running

Comment: try going here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377244/osx-swift-call-function-at-a-specific-date-time

Answer (score 0):

You should use background task if you want to run the function if your application is on the background, not closed. Such as:

```
var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: Your nstimerinterval, target: self, selector: "someBackgroundTask:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

func someBackgroundTask(timer:NSTimer) {

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
        println("You can do background tasks here.")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            println("If you want to update your UI, you should do it here.")

        })
    })
}
```

Comment: In addition to my question, Actually my application should run 1st , 2nd , 3rd day of each month. Do you have any idea about this

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is with an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:). Use something like:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "function_name", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

to create a loop that runs a certain function whenever you want.

Comment: " interval " Leads for what?