# OSX/Swift: Call function at a specific date/time

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to get my app to call a function at specific time intervals. For example, I might want the function to be called every hour on the hour, so at 1:00 AM, 2:00 AM, and so on. I have tried doing this with an NSTimer, but I find that it has trouble staying in sync when resuming after the machine sleeps or is powered off. Is there a way for my app to detect when we have reached a specific date and time and to call a function at that time? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Grand Central Dispatch. Specifically use [dispatch_walltime()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_walltime) to create a `dispatch_time_t` representing the time you want the job to run and then use [dispatch_after()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) to submit the job to Grand Central Dispatch for execution at the specified time.

Answer (score 1):

Run it every minute and test whether ≥ 1h has elapsed since the last invocation.

Comment: Wouldn't that fall out of sync after we resume from sleep/power off? If I shut off the computer for 15 minutes and resumed, wouldn't that just call the function at 1:15, 2:15, etc from that point on instead of on the hour?

Comment: No, you record the last time you executed the action, and only execute it again if at least an hour has passed. If it's a rule that you only want to trigger on the hour, then you also check that it's within a minute of the hour. You also need to decide what to do if several hours have elapsed. Does the "> 1h" rule override the "on the hour" rule, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper method similar to below in combination with the NSTimer.  The timer could fire its selector function every sec/minute/etc in which you pass this helper a pair of currentDate/endDate and when the returned value is <= 0 then execute your timed event function once with a flag and move your endDate forward an hour.

```
func timeBetween(currentDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Double
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Second], fromDate: currentDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])

    return Double(components.second)
}
```